# Checking Left/Right in an int array for Tetris, Android/Java

Tags: java, android, tetris

I'm trying to make a tetris game for android to help learn game programming for android. My goLeft/Rights break right when the button is pressed, the code for going left is in a class separate of the fields int array, and the list parts array. The fields array is accessed by a referenced variable (TetrisWorld tetrisworld;). While part list array is public so accessed through a variable(part) code for which is in the goLeft() code. It breaks at: if(tetrisworld.fields[x][part.y] != 0) Code for left:

```
public void goLeft() {
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        TetrisParts part = parts.get(i);
        x = part.x - 1;
        if(tetrisworld.fields[x][part.y] != 0) {
            noleft = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(noleft == false) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            TetrisParts part = parts.get(i);
            part.x--;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the fields int array:

```
int fields[][] = new int[WORLD_WIDTH][WORLD_HEIGHT];
```

WORLD_WIDTH and WORLD_HEIGHT are both static final ints, width being 9 and height being 19

I've tried putting if(tetrisworld.fields[0][0] == 0) and it still crashes so I don't think it has to do with the variables. Also It doesn't go out of bound even if I haven't added the code to check for that yet because I have the teroid spawning around x = 5 and since I can't go left/right once there's not a chance of that happening

I've tried moving the goLeft/Right methods to the gamescreen class which has a "world = TetrisWorld();" and it still bugs out at the same spot

UPDATE:

Ok just adding:

```
tetrisworld != null
```

to the first if statement fixed it, my question now is, why did it fix it? Why can't I move without this check? It clearly isn't null cause as far as I know; it's fully responsive now.

But an easier way to have solved this which is SOOOO easy is changing `fields` to static... then access it lika so: `TetrisWorld.fields` so my updated code is:

```
public void goLeft()
  {
  noleft = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
     part = parts.get(i);
     if (part.x - 1 < 0 || TetrisWorld.fields[part.x - 1][part.y] != 0)
        {
        noleft = true;
        break;
        }
     }
  if (noleft == false)
     {
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
        part = parts.get(i);
        part.x--;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: A Java program rarely crashes. Most of the time, it throws an exception with a type, a message, and a stack trace. Read them, and post them if you can't understand them.

Comment: How are you setting up the value for `tetrisworld`?

Comment: A game for a beginner? Uh oh, that screams trouble. You should learn the basics of android before taking on such a task. Gaming is one of the harder things to program from my experience.

Comment: lika so: TetrisWorld tetrisworld; @Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I believe I found the answer, referencing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Apparently java will throw an NPE if you don't check for it first if you have a null reference? Is there any way to initialize it without doing a `TetrisWorld tetrisworld = new TetrisWorld();` because it's already created in a different class so i get a thousand errors, an actual stack overflow! lul...     Still not 100% positive. Please comment to verify and possibly suggest a better way to go about this.

Comment: Pass the already created `TetrisWorld` from the class which has it to the class which needs it.

Comment: if you're talking about `TetrisWorld tetrisworld;` I already did that and was getting the Null pointer exception, i just made `fields[][]` static and that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

When you are doing `x = part.x - 1;`, your `x` variable can become lesser tan zero, thus your code will act like `if(tetrisworld.fields[-1][part.y] != 0`

Comment: I have the tetroid centered around x = 5 so it doesn't get close to x = 0 cause I can't even do a goleft/right once, I haven't added that code in yet because I can't even go once as I said, should of said that

Comment: Well, then I need a stacktrace... Look carefully to your device logcat and get a trace. Your app can't fail silently!

Comment: Ok added everything I could find, sure a couple of them are pointless but added them anyways @Olegas

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when trying to access the array in `tetrisworld`. In the line you mention there are several ways that this could occur:

```
if(tetrisworld.fields[x][part.y] != 0) {
```

1. `tetrisworld` could be null.
2. The `fields` member of `tetrisworld` could be null.
3. The second array that you're looking up by using `tetrisworld.fields[x]`.
4. The value of `part` could be null.

Having a quick look through your source code it looks to me like you never initialise `tetrisworld`, either at declaration using:

```
TetrisWorld tetrisworld = new TetrisWorld();
```

Or at some other point which is certain to have happened before your `goLeft()` method is called.

Comment: I tried as you said adding the `= new TetrisWorld();` to that and I got like 50 errors from that so then I just moved the Left and Right methods to the gamescreen class since it has a `world = TetrisWorld();` but it still stops at the same spot, also the button doesn't always register now, takes a few tries... updated the  source @Free

Comment: Also, one time, I did add some code to set all the values of `field[][]` to 0 right at the beginning of the `goLeft()` method so they weren't null. And I've tried putting 0 for the values in: `if(tetrisworld.fields[0][0] !=0) {` and still does the same thing

Comment: If putting 0 for the X and Y values still gets the same error then it's worth checking that `tetrisworld` and `tetrisworld.fields` isn't null. If you change the if statement to  `if(tetrisworld != null && tetrisworld.fields != null && tetrisworld.fields[x][part.y] != 0)` does that change the behaviour at all?